# Getting windows 10's bash to work with console2

Tags: bash, windows-10, console2

I recetly reseted my PC and cant get this to work now.. I dont really remember how I got it to work last time. But I saw this guide: http://sean-bedford.com/console2-bash/

But when I try to change my shell to:

```
C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "c:\windows\system32\bash.exe"
```

I cant start console2.

If I try to run the path in `run` (WIN+R), everything works fine.

If I change the `/c` to `/k` then I can run it but this comes up:

```
'c:\windows\system32\bash.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

But I can runt that path normaly as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bash on Windows is a 64-bit application. If you have a 32-bit Console2, just download the 64-bit version.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files/console-devel/2.00/

And also, with 64-bit Console2, you don't need to wrap bash.exe with the cmd.exe

Just set Shell field into the Console Settings to: `C:\windows\system32\bash.exe ~`

Or if you configure with console.xml file, add `shell="C:\windows\system32\bash.exe ~"` attribute to the `console` element.